# 注意する conjugation and ~てもらう

Tags: conjugations, て-form, giving-and-receiving

I'm to conjugate 注意する and associate it with either of "てあげる", "てくれる" and ”てもらう" in the following sentence:

> 隣の人がうるさくて眠れないので、大家さんから静かにするように(注意する)_____ことにしました。

I picked "注意してもらう", which gives this, and which I translate as follows:

> 隣の人がうるさくて眠れないので、大家さんから静かにするように注意してもらうことにしました。
>
> My neighbour is noisy and I cannot get to sleep, so I decided to get my landlord to ask them to be quiet.

Are my choice and my translation correct?

Answer (score -1):

Your proposition seems good to me:

> 隣の人がうるさくて眠れないので、大家さんから静かにするように注意してもらうことにしました。

<s>Using `てあげる`, would have meant "to tell my landlord to be careful":</s>

> 隣の人がうるさくて眠れないので、大家さんから静かにするように注意してあげることにしました。

Using `てくれる` doesn't quiet fit, though it semanticaly sounds close to `てもらう`.

Comment: `"to tell my landlord to be careful": 大家さんから静かにするように注意してあげる` <-- That would be 「大家さんに注意するように言う」(maybe you meant to write 大家さん***に***静かにするように注意してあげる, "I'll tell the landlord to be *quiet* "). 大家さんから静かにするように注意してあげる doesn't really make sense, I'm afraid..

Comment: @Chocolate rereading the phrase, I'm not really happy with it. It sounds almost right but though is kind of meaning less. I guess it's because only `てもらう` fits.

Comment: One of the downvotes have no explanation. Speechless downvoter, please explain why you down voted. Otherwise, your action is pretty useless. Thx

Comment: `One of the downvotes have no explanation.` <-- およよ？　私、ダウンボートしてないです。。。（アップボートもしてないけど）

Comment: `大家さんから静かにするように注意してあげる` is not grammatically correct: `あげる` is used with `に`, but not with `から` - you cannot say `To give from` (except in extremely contrived sentences, which is the same in Japanese I guess)

Comment: @Chocolate 失礼しました！Thought you were one of downvoters...

Comment: Why is it people are still bashing me instead of giving an answer of their own? I feel this community is not very welcoming.